# Why does Decimal modulo give the wrong sign?

Tags: python, math, modulo

Took ages to track down a bug which essentially boiled down to me assuming that both the below modulos would return a result greater than 0:

```
>>> -0.09 % 0.1
0.010000000000000009  # OK

>>> Decimal('-0.09') % Decimal('0.1')
Decimal('-0.09')      # Not OK -- I expected a positive value!
```

This behaviour seems to go against [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

> The modulo operator always yields a result with **the same sign as its second operand** (or zero)

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Given that the doc you quoted says "always", and that it doesn't qualify that claim by constraining it to any particular types, I think it's fair to say that the documentation is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a bug. This is the (unfortunate) way Decimal works in Python that is not consistent with integers or floats:

> There are some small differences between arithmetic on Decimal objects and arithmetic on integers and floats. When the remainder operator % is applied to Decimal objects, the sign of the result is the sign of the dividend rather than the sign of the divisor:

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 0):

You’re looking at the wrong documentation: the passage you linked applies to built-in numeric types (although this isn’t at all obvious). For `decimal`, you need to look at the [documentation of `decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context.remainder). There it says:

> **`remainder(x, y)`**
>
> Returns the remainder from integer division.
>
> The sign of the result, if non-zero, is the same as that of the original dividend.

And, furthermore:

> The `%` and `//` operators implement the `remainder` and `divide-integer` operations (respectively) as described in the specification.

The fact that this behaviour is inconsistent is quite annoying of course.

Comment: The difference is also explicitly called out in the main "Decimal" section of the docs: "When the remainder operator % is applied to Decimal objects, the sign of the result is the sign of the dividend rather than the sign of the divisor:"

Comment: Agreed that the inconsistency is annoying, though; it probably would have been better to leave `%` and `//` undefined for `Decimal` objects.